FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'products/7WF8Jzbp5aCB8zx9Gm35'. (storage/unauthorized)
I am getting this error whenever i am trying to add new products in my web app

ERROR:  FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'products/7WF8Jzbp5aCB8zx9Gm35'. (storage/unauthorized)

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied."
  }
}

My firebase Security Rules
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    //match /{document=**} {
    //  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 4, 21);
    //}
    
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
    match /products/{productId} {
      allow create,update,delete: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}


Security rules are only meaningful when paired with application code that observes those rules.  Please edit the question to show the relevant app code, and be sure to include your debugging information.  We can't see the path that you're trying to upload to, and we can't see that the user is signed in at that time.
